# Fullscreen mode in emacs24

Tags: macos, emacs, fullscreen

I've recently updated my emacs from version 22 to 24. Lots of things changed, but the most annoying is that fullscreen support disapeared.

I used to use this function:

```
(defun toggle-fullscreen (&optional f)
  (interactive)
  (let ((current-value (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen)))
    (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen
                         (if (equal 'fullboth current-value)
                             (if (boundp 'old-fullscreen) old-fullscreen nil)
                           (progn (setq old-fullscreen current-value)
                                  'fullboth)))))
(global-set-key [f11] 'toggle-fullscreen)
```

But that appears not to work any more. :-)

I'm running on a mac OSX 10.6 and emacs24 [emacs for mac osx](http://emacsformacosx.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, the development code (which will become 24.3) has recently had a patch applied to add fullscreen support under Mac OS X.  So, you might want to try that bleeding edge version.  I don't know much about fullscreen support under Mac OS X, other than the fact that it's been broken in different ways for different version of Mac OS X, so I can't guarantee that the new code will work for your particular case, but if it doesn't, please `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say how you installed Emacs 24, but the Homebrew Emacs formula includes a patch providing the `M-x ns-toggle-fullscreen` command for switching between normal and full-screen modes. It works well, but does not provide the typical OS X Lion full-screen app experience. In particular, it remains on the desktop, obscuring non-full-screen applications, rather than moving to its own space. You can find more details in [this blog post](http://sourcematters.org/2012/04/10/full-screen-emacs-24-for-os-x-lion.html).

Comment: I used emacsformacosx.com and the ns-toggle-fullscreen option but it does not work :(

Comment: The command is not part of the standard Emacs 24 distribution - you need to patch the original source before compiling it (homebrew adds a patch for `ns-toggle-fullscreen` automatically and the linked blog post suggests the use of another patch).

Comment: I've run through the blogpost, and from what I can tell it only works with OSX lion, since the machine I'm on is running Snow Leopard, the solution does not work.

Comment: But you can install the patched Emacs 24 from homebrew and `ns-toggle-fullscreen` will work for you...

Comment: I really cannot see how that will work when I'm not using Lion - I've tried, the instructions in the blog and the patch doesn't even compile.

Comment: The patch in homebrew is a different one (and it's not related to the Lion patch in any way). Both my answer and the post mention the difference.